# Why does numpy.cross() support only 2 or 3 dimensions?

Tags: numpy

Why does `numpy.cross()` support only 2 or 3 dimensions, whereas wikipedia says that we can have cross product even for 7 dimensions?

Comment: The `np.cross` code is Python that you can read for yourself.  My impression is that it has been fine tuned for the 2 and 3 dimension cases.  I can't say whether  any developer has thought about generalizing it or not.  I haven't seen many questions on SO about it, so there's little demand for a generalized version.

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-dimensional_cross_product, the 7 dim cross product makes most sense within an octonian framework, and is multivalued.  `numpy` doesn't implement quaternions, much less octonians.  Look to sympy or other extension packages for these objects.